# Mui Drawer transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I'm working on implementing a Material-UI (MUI) Drawer component with custom transition behavior based on different states.

I'm using the `transitionDuration` prop to control the duration of the drawer's open and close transitions. However, I've encountered an issue where the `transitionDuration` prop only seems to work when the drawer is first opened. I need the transition to occur again when the user clicks on `"Item 1"` inside the drawer, causing the drawer to transition to the left. Additionally, I want the drawer to perform an `"exit"` transition when it is closed.

[Demo Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-blackwell-ftxqh6?file=/src/CustomDrawer.js)